# How to correctly extract the phase of the spectrum in python

Tags: python, numpy, fft, angle, phase

I describe a pulse in the time domain and do a Fourier Transform to convert it to the frequency domain.
I add an e-index polynomial phase `e^{i*phase}`to it in the frequency domain,phase is a polynomial.
At this time, I use the `angle` function under numpy to extract the phase, and what I get is such  dense peaks as shown in the figure. I don't know if this is correct and I don't know how should I extract the polynomial again.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fs = 1e-15
THz = 1e12
nm = 1e-9
c = 3e8
N = 2 ** 13
time_window = 3000 * fs
wavelength = 800 * nm
t = np.linspace(-time_window / 2,time_window / 2, N)
df = np.append(np.linspace(0, N / 2, int(N / 2)),(np.linspace(-N / 2, -1, int(N / 2))))/ time_window
f = c/wavelength + df
dw = 2 * np.pi * df
FWHM = 50 * fs
m = 4 * np.log(2)
A_t = np.exp(-m * t ** 2 * (1 / 2) / FWHM ** 2)
A_w = np.fft.fft(A_t)
GDD = 500 * fs*fs
TOD = 0 * fs*fs*fs
FOD = 0
A_w = np.exp(1j * (GDD / 2.0) * dw**2 +
                                1j * (TOD / 6.0) * dw ** 3+
                                1j * (FOD / 24.0) * dw ** 4) * A_w

fig_1 = plt.figure(1, facecolor='w', edgecolor='k')
ax_1 = fig_1.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
ax_2 = ax_1.twinx()
ax_1.plot(np.fft.fftshift(f/THz),np.fft.fftshift(np.abs(A_w) ** 2 / max(np.abs(A_w) ** 2)),'b')
ax_2.plot(np.fft.fftshift(f/THz),np.fft.fftshift(np.angle(A_w)),'r')
ax_1.set_ylabel('Intensity / a.u.')
ax_2.set_ylabel('Phase / rad')
ax_1.tick_params(axis='y', colors='b')
ax_2.tick_params(axis='y', colors='r')

plt.xlim(300,450)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I know in numpy there is a `unwrap` function, but it doesn't work well

Answer (score 0):

Two things.  To center your data relative to phase, you need to either fftshift your data before the FFT, or flip the sign of the imaginary component in every other result element.

Then look at the magnitude result.  When the magnitudes go sufficiently near zero, the phase becomes that of random numerical noise, rather than informative.  So the phase of near zero magnitudes can be zeroed to make the plot look cleaner.